# show data in popup after ajax load return the resulted data from database

Tags: php, json, jquery

i have a problem that i am unable to solve it. i have users in database. every user have some expiry date of their passport. now i want to popup all those user that have only 3 days left in their expiry of passport on login.

how i did all is when admin login an ajax call goes to getuser.php. select all the users in json formate and return the result. i am ok upto that point but i am unable to do any thing else after that. infact i want to show the return records in popup with ok or cross/cancle button.

below is my ajax call script.

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var url = 'getuser.php';
         $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
         $.each(data, function(index, data) {
       $('#tablebody').append('<tr>');
       $('#tablebody').append('<td>'+data.Emp_num+'</td>');
       $('#tablebody').append('<td>'+data.Emp_id+'</td>');
       $('#tablebody').append('<td>'+data.Eng_name+'</td>');
       $('#tablebody').append('<td>'+data.Pass_exipry_date+'</td>');
       $('#tablebody').append('</tr>');
         });
     });
  });

 </script>
```

Below is the code of server side scripting(getuser.php)

```
  <?php 
  $conn = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
  if(!$conn){
  die('Mysql connection error '.mysql_error());
  }

  $db = mysql_select_db('db',$conn);
  if(!$db){
  die('Database selection failed '.mysql_error());
  }

  $expiry = mysql_query("select * from table where PASSPORT_EXPIRED_DATE > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 3 DAY");

  $data = array();
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($expiry)){
  $row_data = array(
  'Emp_num' => $row['EMPLOYEE Number'], 
  'Emp_id' => $row['EMPLOYEE ID'],
  'Eng_name' => $row['ENGLISH FULL NAME'],
  'Pass_exipry_date' => $row['PASSPORT_EXPIRED_DATE']
  );
 array_push($data, $row_data);
 }
 echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Below is the table where i am appending the ajax response data

```
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
       <tr>
         <th>Employee Number</th>
         <th>Employee ID</th>
         <th>English Name</th>
         <th>Passport Expirey Date</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody id="tablebody">
   </tbody>
</table>
```

now i want to show this whole table in a popup with ajax returned data from database.i am searching for it but i am unable to understand how to do it.

Comment: is their anyone who know the solution

Comment: i dont know what happend to stackoverflow no one is here to discuss this issue with me its my second time i am posting this question but no one is answering

Answer (score 0):

That's not how `append()` works. You can only append entire elements. Try this:

```
$('<tr/>')
    .append('<td>' + data.Emp_num + '</td>')
    .append('<td>' + data.Emp_id + '</td>')
    .append('<td>' + data.Eng_name + '</td>')
    .append('<td>' + data.Pass_exipry_date + '</td>')
    .appendTo('#tablebody');
```